# Array swap - 2d array

Tags: java, arrays

I'm working on swapping indices in a two-dimensional array. I seem to be on the right track, but it's not swapping the array in the way I want.

The first row's index `j` needs to be swapped with row 2's index `j`:

```
for (int j = 0; j < array.length ; j++){  
     int temp = array[row1][j]
     array[row1][j]=array[j][row1]
     array[j][row1] = temp ;
}
```

Any ideas on how to best approach this would be appreciated.

Comment: Please tell us what is "the way you want. Are you trying to transpose a square matrix?

Comment: do you want to get from `[[0,1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8,9]]` to `[[5,6,7,8,9],[0,1,2,3,4]]`?

Comment: Yes. However, do keep in mind I have 4 rows. They aren't swappable in a specific order. I can swap row 1 with row 3 if I want, or row 2 with row -1, etc.

Answer (score 4):

As the two-dimensional array in java is actually a array of references to other arrays, you can simply swap the references as shown below:

```
public static void swapRows(int array[][], int rowA, int rowB) {
   int tmpRow[] = array[rowA];
   array[rowA] = array[rowB];
   array[rowB] = tmpRow;
}
```

**/edit**: edited the answer as I previously misinterpreted it**

Comment: hmmm, I guess one could even start at `int col=row+1` as e.g. array[10][10] doesn't need swapping with its opposite

Comment: Nope. I'm still not getting this right. I have to loop through indices j, and swap those indices from the first row to the 2nd row.

Comment: @MH1993 Edited the answer. Is that what you want?