# Java: Swap 2D array rows that contain minimum and maximum values

Tags: java, arrays

I'm having problems making a function that would swap a 2Dimensional Arrays rows, that include the biggest and the smallest values.

I cant think of a way how to make it into a code. I need a helping hand. I tried to edit the code of min and max value in an array to give me the row index of the biggest and smallest numbers but i got confused and im not sure how to do it. Pls help me on how to get the arrays row index of the  max and min values so I can put it into the row switching function.

```
ANSWER EXAMPLE:
if the array was like this:
5   2  1  8
15 -4  5  18
7   3  44 9
12  1  18 76 
it would swap it like this:
5   2  1  8
12  1  18 76
7   3  44 9
15 -4  5  18

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        {
        
        final int kolonna = (int) (Math.random()*(9-1+1)+1);
        final int rinda = (int) (Math.random()*(9-1+1)+1);
        
        int [][] arr = new int [kolonna][rinda];
            
        //fill the grid
        for (int rin = 0; rin < arr.length; rin++) {
            
            for (int kol = 0; kol < arr[rin].length; kol++) {
                
                arr[rin][kol] = (int) (Math.random() * 201) - 100;
            }
        }
print2Dmas(arr);
System.out.println();
int mazs=0;
int liels=0;
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
int rowWithMin = i;
int rowWithMax = i;
    for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
        if (rowWithMin > arr[i][j]) {
            rowWithMin = i;
            mazs = j;
        }

        if (rowWithMax < arr[i][j]) {
            rowWithMax = i;
            liels = j;
        }
    }
    if (rowWithMin != rowWithMax){
        swapRows(arr, rowWithMin, rowWithMax);}
}
print2Dmas(arr);
      }
    }   
    public static void print2Dmas(int mas[][]) {
        for(int i = 0; i < mas.length; i++) {

            for(int j = 0; j < mas[i].length; j++) {
                    
                System.out.print(mas[i][j] + " ");
                //System.out.println();
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
    
    public static void swapRows(int array[][], int rowA, int rowB) {
           int tmpRow[] = array[rowA];
           array[rowA] = array[rowB];
           array[rowB] = tmpRow;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Store the row with the min and max value. Try this:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        final int kolonna = (int) (Math.random()*(9-1+1)+1);
        final int rinda = (int) (Math.random()*(9-1+1)+1);
        
        int [][] arr = new int [kolonna][rinda];
            
        //fill the grid
        for (int rin = 0; rin < arr.length; rin++) {
            for (int kol = 0; kol < arr[rin].length; kol++) {
                arr[rin][kol] = (int) (Math.random() * 201) - 100;
            }
        }
        print2Dmas(arr);
        System.out.println();
        int rowWithMin = 0;
        int rowWithMax = 0;
        int minElement = arr[0][0];
        int maxElement = arr[0][0];
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) { 
                if (minElement > arr[i][j]) {
                    minElement = arr[i][j];
                    rowWithMin = i;
                }

                if (maxElement < arr[i][j]) {
                    maxElement = arr[i][j];
                    rowWithMax = i;
                }
            }
        }
        if (rowWithMin != rowWithMax){
            swapRows(arr, rowWithMin, rowWithMax);
        }
        print2Dmas(arr);
    }
   
    public static void print2Dmas(int mas[][]) {
        for(int i = 0; i < mas.length; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < mas[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(mas[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
    
    public static void swapRows(int array[][], int rowA, int rowB) {
           int tmpRow[] = array[rowA];
           array[rowA] = array[rowB];
           array[rowB] = tmpRow;
    }
}
```

Reference:
[Array swap - 2d array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13280583/array-swap-2d-array/13280668)

Other example:
[Swapping rows of double 2d array java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50332733/swapping-rows-of-double-2d-array-java?rq=1)

Comment: `int mazs=0;
int liels=0;
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
int rowWithMin = arr[i][0];
int rowWithMax = arr[i][0];
    for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
        if (rowWithMin > arr[i][j]) {
            rowWithMin = i;
            mazs = j;
        }

        if (rowWithMax < arr[i][j]) {
            rowWithMax = i;
            liels = j;
        }
    }
    if (rowWithMin != rowWithMax){
        swapRows(arr,mazs,liels);}
}
print2Dmas(arr);` Pls help me im super dumb right now i dont know what am i doing wrong im sorry :(

Comment: You are calling `swapRows(arr, rowA, rowB)` wrong.
Use: `swapRows(arr, rowWithMin, rowWithMax)`
So you have to pass the two rows, which have to be changed.

Comment: When i do so, it gives me a error  java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -20 out of bounds for length 8 at Main.swapRows. Its says the error is here: `int tmpRow[] = array[rowA];`

Comment: Oh I see you are doing:
`int rowWithMax = arr[i][0]`
Look at my code above, store the row, not the element in the row.
so only `int rowWithMax = i`

EDIT: 
It would be easier to understand if you could update your original post with your current code and clean it up a bit

Comment: im using `int rowWithMax = i` but the rows wont change, I dont understand whats wrong :(

Comment: I updatet my answer above with the full code, does this help?

Comment: Finally I got it, thank you very much! I appreciate it more than you think.

Comment: Good. If this helped you I would be grateful if you mark my answer as helpful.